# Alternative ways to enter English letters in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login-screen

I don't know how but the English layout was removed from Ubuntu. At the moment I can't log in, because my password contains English letters. Also, when I'm starting it in advanced mode as root, I still can type only Russian letters and can't execute any command. So I'm trying to find any way to log in.

Comment: Can you boot the system's installation media again, on that system?  If you do that, can you type the expected letters, with the administrative-level powers typical of a "root" account?

Answer (score 1):

Try the old technique of using Alt-codes.

Hold down Alt, then type in the two or three digit number that corresponds to the desired letter, then release Alt.

Make sure to type the number on the numpad.  (Yes, this might require holding Fn if using a laptop keyboard with a reduced size.)

To see what number to type, check an ASCII table like what is seen at http://www.asciitable.com/

in short, 65 is capital A, 66 is capital B, 67 is capital C, and so on.  Lowercase letters are 32 higher, so lowercase a is 97, lowercase b is 98, and so on.

13 typically represents the same thing as pressing the Enter key.

Comment: +1 I came to post this very same answer.

Comment: I've already tried it. It doesn't work (ubuntu 20.04, gnome 3)